# Encoding a mediumtext field from a databse with php in JSON, it returns null

Tags: php, mysql, json, database

Hi Guys when i encode  a mediumtext field form a database in JSON this is "NULL" obviusly if i print this in php i see the full text. How can i solve this? Thanks for the help. The code is:

```
  $query = $conn->query("SELECT id,introtext FROM `content`  ORDER BY content.id DESC ");

     while($e = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
       {
         if($e["id"]==$rs["content_id"])    
          {
            $out[]=$e;

          }

        }




 }




$conn->close();

echo json_encode($out);
```

----EDIT-----

I solved, the json encode needs a string encoded int UTF-8 so i added before the json encode the UTF-8 encode

```
$e["introtext"]=utf8_encode($e["introtext"]);
```

Comment: If you print_r($out) at the end of this file, do you get a correct array? (I see some strange closing bracket there)

Comment: What is the encoding for the "`mediumtext`" field? Besides: you could probably optimize your SQL to not scan the entire table for one ID: `"SELECT id,introtext FROM `content` WHERE id = '" .  $rs["content_id"] . "' ORDER BY content.id DESC "`

Comment: skobaljic   i used print_r and the array is correct  thanks, the closing bracket are part of a previous code i didn't copy